# Are inter-service WCF REST calls the best way to communicate between application components?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest

As a part of a decoupling process to facilitate horizontal application scaling, we are slowly forking out the stateless parts of our application into separate services, which are either served on the same AWS IIS instance, or spun off onto a new one if they need to.

It is becoming apparent that some services that comprise the web service are ideal candidates for decoupling. However, I am unsure as to whether WCF REST calls are the best way to communicate to each other.

What is the best solution to provide inter-component communication in a hosted application via WCF? Currently there are no framework restrictions for the services, so anything .net is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest is only good if you're calling your services from a client that you have less control over and need to provide a standard interface to, or are calling over the web where http protocol must be used.

If you have a system where your client is controlled by you and can use any mechanism to call the service, then use a communication system that is more efficient. If you use WCF you can use the net.tcpip protocol which will be much faster (or WWS which is even faster) or go the whole hog and use something like protocol buffers, thrift or another RPC to get the most performance.

I would also run these as dedicated services, outside of IIS so they are less dependant on the whole web infrastructure. You can then deploy them on any box and harden them without the "monoculture" risk, or rewrite them for efficiency in c++.

Comment: I'm thinking of just using WCF net.tcp to send serialised objects. It is good enough for what I need, and allows me to stick to what I more-or-less know, and has the bonus of being able to switch between IIS, standalone, or services. [Good example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/717327/WCF-NetTcp-Binding) that I plan to take in.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a full .NET environment, use WCF without REST, so that the clients can easily create local class references and easily be able to communicate over the web service layer. Ideally, expose (and consume) the services as net.tcp binding if you really want an optimal solution.

Leave the REST(ful) endpoints exposed through WCF for web client consumption, where XML and/or JSON is involved.

The biggest benefit in WCF is you can expose multiple endpoints on the same contracts (interfaces), so your .NET middle layer can be exposed via one endpoint, while other services can be exposed via web endpoints (such as webHttpBinding) from the clients that need it.

Comment: This is one of the features that is looking promising, as I can create the service itself right now, but configure how it is exposed later, and even adapt it for different consumption simultaneously.